# Find the Slope JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a codewars problem below:

- Given an array of 4 integers
  [a,b,c,d] representing two points (a, b) and (c, d), return a string representation of the slope of the line joining these two points.
- For an undefined slope (division by 0), return undefined . Note that the "undefined" is case-sensitive.
- a:x1
  b:y1
  c:x2
  d:y2
- Assume that [a,b,c,d] and the answer are all integers (no floating numbers!). Slope: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope*

I can get the slope for any numbers when 0 is not in the denominator (bottom of the fraction). However, whenever 0 is in the denominator, I get this message:

*expected undefined to equal '0'

I'm not sure on how to solve this part. My code so far is below:

```
function slope(points) {
  let a = (points[0]);
  let b = (points[1]);
  let c = (points[2]);
  let d = (points[3]);
  function findSlope(a,b,c,d) {
    if (c-a === 0) {
      return 'undefined';
    }
    else if (c-a !== 0) {
      let slope = (d-b)/(c-a);
      let answer = slope.toString();
      return answer;
    }
    else {
      return 'undefined';
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it wants the string `return 'undefined'` and not the value `return undefined` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening probably because you are not passing values.

[Try this :)](https://jsfiddle.net/vaibhavl1998/c4kwpxrh/3/)

```
function slope(points) {
  let a = points[0];
  let b = points[1];
  let c = points[2];
  let d = points[3];

  function findSlope(a, b, c, d) {
    if (c - a === 0) {
      return "undefined";
    } else if (c - a !== 0) {
      let slope = (d - b) / (c - a);
      let answer = slope.toString();
      return answer;
    } else {
      return "undefined";
    }
  }

  console.log(findSlope(a, b, c, d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `'undefined'`, not `undefined`. Change this and then it should work.

Comment: Hi, that didn't work either. I think they want it as a string. Thank you for your help, though!